# Simple rewrite with subfolder

Tags: mod-rewrite

I want to point:
www.reneebuller.com/paintings/busy-pair-humming-bird-painting.html to
www.reneebuller.com/painting-details.cfm?ID=136&Type=Bird

Is this the correct rewrite?  I'm not sure how to account for the /paintings/ folder.

```
RewriteRule ^paintings/busy-pair-humming-bird-painting.html painting-details.cfm?ID=136&Type=Bird [NC, R=301, L]
```

Comment: How do you want your URL to appear in the browser because you have a 301 redirect in your rule? and is paintings a real folder?

Answer (score 0):

The above rewrite is correct.  It just takes time for the server to process the .htaccess file.